# filter out rows with 0s from dataTable when heatMap boxOnClick

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I would like to filter out rows that have an FTE value of 0 from my dataTable, but only when a box(s) are selected from my heatMap. If no box(s) are selected then the dataTable should show rows with FTE value of 0.

I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/PgVi1TS8WDw talking about disguising a group as a dimension.

dataTable dimension:

```
var dimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Resource + ' ' + d.Month + ' ' + d.FTE;
});
```

dataTabel:

```
var index = 0;      
detailedTable = dc.dataTable('.detailedTable')
    .dimension(dimension)
    .group(function (d) {
        return '';
     })
     .columns([
         function (d) {
             index = index + 1;
             return resultStart + index;
         },
         function (d) {
             return d.Resource;
         },
         function (d) {
             return d.FTE;
         },
         function (d) {
             return d.Month;
         }
      ])
      .size(Infinity)
      .on('renderlet', function (c) {
          index = 0,
          displayResult();
       });
```

heatMap boxOnClick:

```
heatMap.boxOnClick(function (d) {

    //filter dataTable here

    //Deflut boxOnClick:
    var filter = d.key;
    dc.events.trigger(function () {
        heatMap.filter(filter);
        heatMap.redrawGroup();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/_M_M_/fcjhxa16/19/

Comment: This is going to be pretty messy, since crossfilter & dc.js only support one filter set currently. If you have any other charts, you wouldn't want to use a crossfilter group since it will also be affected by the other charts. So you're pretty much doing an end run around crossfilter and implementing filtering yourself. I've run out of free time for today but I could take a look tomorrow if you add more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh! I guess  mean that you only want to filter the dataTable when something is selected in the heatMap, and not filter it otherwise? That sounds doable. When I first read this I thought you meant that you wanted the dataTable filtered by the heatMap somehow independent of other filters. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my confusion - if I understood you correctly this time, this is completely trivial and it's one of the rare cases where you want a "fake dimension".

The fake dimension will read the original dimension and filter it based on a predicate. The predicate will say "either the row has FTE > 0 or there is nothing selected on the heatMap"

```
function filtered_dimension(dimension, f) {
  return {
    top: function(N) {
      return dimension.top(N).filter(f);
    },
    bottom: function(N) {
      return dimension.bottom(N).filter(f);
    }
  };
}

var dimension_with_no_fte_zeros_if_heatmap_selected = filtered_dimension(dimension, function(row) {
  return row.FTE || heatMap.filters().length === 0;
});

detailedTable = dc.dataTable('.detailedTable')
  .dimension(dimension_with_no_fte_zeros_if_heatmap_selected)
```

You don't need a click handler - that's too low level - and you're not aggregating anything, just filtering.

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/q23pdhv1/7/).